# Limit the length of an inputted string in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am a complete beginner in Python and I'm trying to make improvements in my code for my GCSE Computer Science coursework. 
All I want to be able to do is limit the number of digits inputted to 7.
Here is all of what I have so far:

```
print("Hello")
time.sleep(0.5)
print("What is your 7-digit product number?")
while True:
try:
    productnumber=  (str(int(input(" "))))
    break
except ValueError:
    print("Please only enter numbers")
    time.sleep(1)
    print()
    print("What is your 7-digit number?")
```

Any help is appreciated, I tried adding a nested loop but I've had no luck so far with anything I do, as I mentioned before, I am a compleeete beginner. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please edit your post and add the exact/specific error you're observing. This will help others more easily help you.

Comment: @xlm Although I've already got my answer, I'll definitely do that, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: check `if len(productnumber) <= 7`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code above is not indented properly because nothing is inside the infinite loop starting with `while True:`. I suspect just the `try`-`except` block is supposed to go in there. What you need to limit the entry to seven characters is an `if`. Consider the following:

```
while True:
  try:
    productnumber = str(int(input(" ")))
    if len(productnumber) > 7:
      print("You may only enter seven digits")
    else:
      break
  except ValueError:
    print("Please only enter numbers")
    time.sleep(1)
    print()
    print("What is your 7-digit number?")
```

The `len` functions computes the length of a string.

There are several other ways to make your code better including using camelCase for your variable names.

Happy python learning!

Comment: Thank you so much for your super fast reply, I really appreciate it! Also thanks for the advice, I incorporated your code into mine and it worked perfectly! Thank you so so much, you're an absolute life saver!

Comment: Read [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id45). `snake_case` is recommended for method and variable names, not `camelCase`. This isn't JavaScript.

Comment: @MattDMo I see! Thank you very much for telling me!